# Hangman Program: Loop Validation

Tags: python

I am writing a hangman game program in python and have run into a problem concerning validating loops. Here is an example of the type of problem:

```
    def loopGet():
        condition = True
        while condition == True:
            userInput = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
            # assigns boolean value to condition
            condition = ifWon()
            # returns condition
            return condition
            #assigns boolean value
            condition = ifLost()
            #return condition
            return condition
```

Pretending that ifWon() and ifLost() are already created, this is an example of what's going and what I am trying to figure out. In my program, even if both return True, the loop ends. If one returns True and the other False, it still ends. I am under the impression that if "condition" returns True, the loop should keep running; yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop "ends" because the method's execution stops at the `return` statement. Since your `return` statement is inside your while loop, it appears that you condition is not working.

Once you move the `return` statement outside your loop, you'll get your expected results.

---

```
def game():

    isWinner = False
    while isWinner == False:
       # as the user for a guess
       # check the guess
       isWinner = isWon()
    return "You won!"
```

You set a variable to the condition that you want to change. So `isWinner = False`, then `while isWinner == False:` do your loop. If `isWon()` returns `True` or `False`, then in your while `isWinner = isWon()`. You don't need `isLost()`, as we want the loop to exit when the user has won.

Comment: Hmm alright, but if I am trying to make the while loop dependent on ifWon() and ifLost(), how is that possible? Say for example that the loop passes in a parameter to each of these functions for them to validate, so it is required to have them inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to loop until ifWon() or ifLost() are True.

In the original code, when you 'return condition' outside an "if", you'll just leave the loop right away. In fact, you'll never reach ifLost(), because you'll just bail out in the line before that.

I don't think you need "condition" at all... just loop until you get to a True, and return then. Note how the returns are inside an if, so you only return if True.

```
  def loopGet():
    while True:
        userInput = raw_input("Enter a string: ")
        # do something with input
        if ifWon():
            return 'Won'
        if ifLost()
            return 'Lost'
```

Some people might object to the nested return, but that's a pretty straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Just to clarify, but why would the code bail out before ifLost() if condition returned True? And if ifWon() and ifLost() are returning boolean values, won't the if statements run no matter what?

Comment: @crackhamster because the code will "bail" as soon as it reaches a `return` statement. and you always run `return condition` right after ifWon() so it will always bail there. Rob Y has made it so it won't reach a return statement unless ifWon() is true or ifLost() is true.